# CKEditor breaking images on XPages

Tags: ckeditor, xpages, lotus-domino, mime

I've been trying to solve this issue for a week now, and so far not so good.

An **XPages** application mimics an email client, with a `<xp:inputRichText>` connected to a `RichText` field in a `Form`. Nothing out of the ordinary.

When an image file gets embedded via the *Insert Image* button on *CKEditor*, and the filename has non-ASCII characters, the resulting MIME bodies register discrepant names, breaking the mail.

[image]

In this case, the original filename was **atenção.jpg**, but names get messy on `Body` field.

I sincerely appreciate any advice

Comment: By the way, HCL Domino 10.0.1

Comment: I suggest that you create a support case with HCL and ask for their help

Answer (score 1):

I did a few tests and I see inconsistencies even in v12. Strangely, the Notes client seems to be able to open such emails. (I tried external email on v9.0.1 and Outlook could not display the image).

As Per suggested, you should open a support case with HCL. They have implemented some fixes in this area recently for 12.0.2.